# WCF Service Method Overloading issue - Help needed

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, .net-framework-version

I've a WCF web service method (over **3.5 NET Framework**) which needs to be refactored to use optional input parameters. Mi investigation concluded optional parameteres as a concept is being introduced on 4.0 so I need to do some workaround to solve my issue. My code update looks like this:

```
partial class Class1: IService {

    public int MethodName ( int param1, string param2 )
    {
         // code here
    }

    public int MethodName ( int param1)
    {
         // code here
         string param2 = FillInInternally();
         return this.MethodName(param1, param2);
    }
```

I've also updated my operation contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Alias1")]
    int MethoName(int param1, string param2);

    [OperationContract(Name = "Alias2")]
    int MethoName(int param1);

}

public partial class ServiceClient : ClientBase <IService>, IService
{

    public int MethoName(int param1, string param2)
    {
       return Channel.MethodName(param1, param2);
    }

    public int MethoName(int param1)
    {
       return Channel.MethodName(param1);
    }
}
```

Having that explained, I was able to get the Web Service correctly build. Besides oh that Integration Tests also ran perfectly. After that, I needed to install on the server and when trying to test the WSDL, I've faced an issu indicating an error on the svc file at column 1, row 1 ( please note I'm not including the exact error message because I rolled back the WS to the previous version to avoid prod issue during the weekend).

My question is: does somebody think I'm missing something from development? Or will I be able to get my WCF service method correctly overloaded when the "installation?" issues is solved?.

Any comments will be welcome.

Thanks,

.NET Framework 3.5
Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition
 C#

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your service contract but without the actual error it will be hard to tell. What was generating the error -- adding a service reference, browsing to the WSDL, or calling a method?

Comment: You mentioned that the error message points to the .svc file, col 1, row 1; but you didn't include the .svc file's contents in your question.  Aside from that, the code you have shown looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually constructing the `ServiceClient` class? I recommend you to use the **svcutil.exe** tool to generate the proxy and don't encourage yourself to do the modifications directly in the generated proxy code.

If you have generated the proxy through the tool or VS add service reference you should see the `IService` and the `ServiceClient` should look something like this,

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    int Alias1(int param1, string param2);

    int Alias2(int param1);
}

public partial class ServiceClient : ClientBase <IService>, IService
{
    // other stuff
    public int Alias1(int param1, string param2)
    {
       return base.Channel.Alias1(param1, param2);
    }

    public int Alias2(int param1)
    {
       return base.Channel.Alias2(param1);
    }
}
```

Note that your client have the methods as `Alias1` and `Alias2` not `MethodName`. Please make sure yourself you have the right proxy to talk to service.